# Rails Remote Development Server iPad/Laptop Demos

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ipad, remote-access, demo

I have a Rails application running on a remote Linux desktop at work via localhost. I wanted to be able to do live demos when I'm away from my desktop for business meetings and such without going through the hassle of pushing to my production server. I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to perhaps remotely connect to my desktop and run my Rails application on another device as if it was running locally? The remote device in question could be something like an iPad or net-book.

My application is sitting on a Github repository if it counts for anything, with that in mind would it be easier to just get rails up and running on an iPad and download the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if safari on the ipad would support it, but for the netbook scenario I think proxying through an [ssh tunnel](https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html) would probably work best (I'm assuming you don't want to deal with the lag involved with a graphical remote desktop connection).

You could also deploy to an alternate environment like heroku or temporarily provision a publicly accessible VM somewhere for demo purposes.

Comment: Is Heroku free for bare-minimum? I expect at most 1-2 users in regards to traffic for the time frame that I would have my application running (probably for an hour or two at most). Also I'll mainly be demoing layout changes and I don't need a whole lot of processing power.

Comment: Never mind it looks like I can get by with the bare-minimum for free!